# What system app stores the cellular network settings?

Tags: applications, settings, data-connection, system

Before installing a new ROM, I backed up all data from my system apps using Titanium.  I installed the new ROM, and also put in a new SIM card from a different network (so it was in on first boot-up of the new ROM).  Everything worked great on the new network, until I restored my backups.  The settings for the network (matching the current SIM) were overwritten by the settings for the old network (matching the previous SIM), and data completely stopped working.

My question is, **what app stores the data network settings?**  If I know then I can restore data for everthing except that app (or apps) and not need to start from scratch if I change SIMs again.  Additionally, is there any way I can trigger the phone to go "Oh look, the settings don't match this SIM, how 'bout we update the settings?"

I have a Samsung Galaxy S Vibrant running Froyo (Bionix v1.3 with TouchWiz).

Comment: I have a closely related issue - migrating from Project Fi to Sprint, only 3G is available - LTE only becomes available after a factory reset. However, if I restore the data partition using TWRP, LTE goes away again and only 3G is available. Unfortunately, no luck/improvement wiping SMS/MMS/APN storage...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`[SMS/MMS/APN] Dialer Storage 2.2`.

Answer (score 2):

I would think that the following would probably be likely candidates:

- TelephonyProvider
- SettingsProvider (maybe)

Does the data network work if you reboot?
What if you restore with the "old sim", then put in the new sim?

Comment: Here are a couple other candidates that I see in my Titanium: Settings Storage 2.2,[SMS/MMS/APN] Dialer Storage 2.2, Onetime initializer.  I have a Motorola on a CDMA network so you may not even have these.

Comment: Hmm.  I'll make a backup and start experimenting with these apps and my SIMs.  (Ryan: No, it doesn't work if I reboot).